# Delete files from remote server using TFS build/release definition

Tags: powershell, tfs, tfsbuild

I am using TFS v2015 to deploy a web application to a remote server. Due to the way our project is structured (as a web site project) the build ends up creating a separate DLL for each .cs. The names of the DLL files are random and change on each deploy. This has resulted in 25,000+ files in the bin folder with names like "App_Web_0bbazvic.dll".

What I would like to do is, before copying files to target machine, delete all files matching the pattern "/bin/app_code_*.dll" from the remote bin directory.

I have considered using the "Machine File Copy" with the option "clean target" enabled, but I don't want to delete the entire directory. I can explain my reasons for this in more detail if requested.

I am also considering the "Power Shell on Target Machine" task. Any suggestions would be appreciated. Also, the remote server is not in the same domain as the build agent.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using simple [Delete Task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/tasks/utility/delete-files?view=vsts) without even going to PowerShell assuming your files are located the same location where the agent is running.

Like this

[image]

For deleting files in remote path you can use the [Remote delete task](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=saeidbabaei.remotedeletesaeid)

Like this
[image]

Comment: It is definitely a remote machine I am trying to delete from. I tried using the 3rd party plugin you mention above, but get the error "The WinRM client cannot process the request. Default authentication may be used with an IP address under the following conditions: the transport is HTTPS or the destination is in the TrustedHosts list, and explicit credentials are provided. Use winrm.cmd to configure TrustedHosts....."

I am not familiar with WinRM. Can it be used if the target is not in the same domain as the agent?

Comment: @MikeH follow [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/6e253c36-6034-419c-81d1-ad4050701f51/build-automation-throwing-error-to-access-virtual-machine-which-has-to-perform-coded-ui-test?forum=TFService) solution, which might help with you with configure the winRM

Answer (score 1):

You can add something like this as an inline script if you are able to use WinRM.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Path\To\Files -recurse -include app_code_*.dll | Remove-item
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/tasks/deploy/powershell-on-target-machines?view=vsts